# Store Password For Current Terminal Session

Tags: security, authentication, go, ssh

I am writing a command line app in Go that allows automating the configuration of networking devices over SSH. Unfortunately, most of these devices are configured for password authentication rather than key authentication. Is there a way to temporarily and securely store the user's password for only the current terminal session? Similar to how setting an environment variable with `export ENV_VAR=<value>` only stores the environment variable for the current session. For example, a user opens the terminal, runs my CLI, and is prompted for their password. For subsequent calls to my program, I'd like to not prompt the user for their password again. If the user closes their terminal then comes back later, however, I would want the password prompt to reappear when my CLI is called. If possible, I would like to do this without using a database since the number of users of my CLI will be very small.

Comment: You can prompt user to get the value, then store in a variable var. Use that $var everywhere then. It will exist for the terminal session only. This can solve your purpose.

Comment: Isn't this assuming that all devices share the same password? Who does that?

Comment: Perhaps storing credentials for some amount of time is a viable alternative, [just like sudo can cache your password](https://superuser.com/a/275173)? I, for one, almost never close some of my terminals. Perhaps there are cryptographic methods that render the ciphertext unusable after some time. Then you can just store credentials in a file.

Comment: Just thinking here, you might want to create a box which acts like a tunnel.  That box can use `key authentication`. Go ssh's into that box, which then tunnels + proxies to the other box. The session password if it's the same can be a ENV var on the tunnel box.  If that's a bit much have the command line tool save the users password as a local ENV on that user's own box and look for it there with os.Getenv.  So the user gets prompted once and the password is stored locally etc. There should be an update password flag just incase it needs to change.

Comment: Even better, the first time the user uses the cli, create a folder in the root path `~.env/`, save an env file there, which contains the password, that can looked up later, update rules still apply. That's literally how aws cli tools work.

Comment: @reticentroot I tried storing the hashed password in an env file, but then I have no way to compare the users’s password to the hashed password without prompting the user. I’d rather not store anyone’s password as plain text in a file or env variable.

Comment: @mwalto7 Can you use a remote config? In that way the key to hash against is accessible everywhere? I also don't see a way to use the passwords otherwise. It's either a DB they hit or it's stored locally on their own boxes like other configs. If you want the passwords to have more security store them in a env with the correct permissions so that the user has to sudo to read them. There are some free DBs you can use in sandbox mode if it comes that to that.